# SSMA Migration error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am doing migration from MYSQL to SQL SERVER. One of my table not migrated with reason
as follows

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_tb` (`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username`    
 varchar(30) NOT NULL, `password` text NOT NULL,  `salt_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `emailid` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NULL,  
 `country` int(5) DEFAULT NULL, `pincode` int(8) DEFAULT '0', `dob` date NOT NULL   
 DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
```

Column 'dob' does not allow DBNull.Value.

I am using SQL SERVER Migration Assistant (SSMA)
  Please suggest..

Comment: The error message pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

```
int(8) DEFAULT '0', dob date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1500-01-01', >> YYYY-MM-DD
```

You musn't write default value 0, but must 1. Cause your `dob date NOT NULL` this mean that it can't have NULL value, but cause of your default value is 0 and become `0000-00-00`, so it just like NULL,, tried to change it to `1`

Of course, date value would not have 00 as day and 00 as month or even the impossible 0000 as year. So try to set the year to default value as the minimum of years in your database. something like 2000 or what you like

Comment: Does it mean this int(8) DEFAULT '0', dob date NOT NULL DEFAULT 1?

Comment: AS it is a dob column I need to put some default value in MYSQL so that while migration it should not give me error as mentioned above. So please provide me the date field syntax, which I need to change in MYSQL so that there wont be any error..

Comment: I have reedit my answer before  "int(8) DEFAULT '0', dob date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1500-01-01', >> YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: I tried with changing the column defination like `dob` date NOT NULL which is not working..

Comment: Is there any other way? Instead of having 1500-01-01 as dob. I need to add something which can will give me 0000-00-00 in sql server after migration

Comment: I tried 3 things 1> '1500-01-01' which works.2> NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' is not a correct syntax,and for NOT NULL the migration is not happening.

Comment: If you force to be 0000-00-00, there just a way, NOT NULL change to NULL, that's all, all just delete the NOT NULL